# How to make an object move on any direction?

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx, sprite

I have a gun sprite that rotates 360 degrees,I wan't it to fire bullets on any direction, how do I do that? I can't just increment the x,y coordinates of the bullet cause it will just go up,down,left and right.

EDIT:
The bullet movement seems only to rotate but not going anywhere or outside the screen

```
 bulletPosition.x=MathUtils.cosDeg(cannonObj.cannonAngle())*2;
        bulletPosition.y=MathUtils.sinDeg(cannonObj.cannonAngle())*2;
        bulletVelocity.x=MathUtils.cosDeg(cannonObj.cannonAngle())*10;
        bulletVelocity.y=MathUtils.sinDeg(cannonObj.cannonAngle())*10;

        bulletPosition.x+=bulletVelocity.x*deltaTime;
        bulletPosition.y+=bulletVelocity.y*deltaTime;

//spawning bullets
 public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        bulletIterator=bullets.iterator();
        while(bulletIterator.hasNext()){
            Sprite sprite=bulletIterator.next();
            sprite.draw(batch);
            sprite.setPosition(bulletPosition.x,bulletPosition.y);
        }
```

Comment: Generally firing a bullet is really quick so the player won't notice the physics behind. However it is much cleaner to include laws from the physics for bullet speed, gravity, ... And it could be very useful later on.

Comment: How about implementing the movement of the bullet? Based on the angle of the gun sprite.Can you help me with that please

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector gunPos; // the gun position,dah
Vector bulletPos; //the bullet position
Vector bulletVelocity; //need explanation?
float gunAngle; //the rotation of the gun in degrees
float distanceFromCenter=gunSize.x/2; //the distance from the gun center you want the bullet to appear

bulletPos.x=MathUtils.cosDeg((gunAngle)) * distanceFromCenter;
bulletPos.y=MathUtils.cosDeg((gunAngle)) * distanceFromCenter;
bulletPos.plus(gunPos);

bulletVelocity.x=MathUtils.cosDeg((gunAngle)) * bulletSpeed;
bulletVelocity.y=MathUtils.cosDeg((gunAngle)) * bulletSpeed;
```

Comment: One last thing plss, how do you set the velocity? on position you can do sprite.setPosition(bulletPos.x,bulletPos.y);

Comment: @masterYao09 , you just have a vector velocity and on each frame you do sprite.position.x+=velocity.x*Gdx.graphics.getDelta() ; sprite.position.y+=velocity.y*Gdx.graphics.getDelta() ; . since its a very basic question and shows that you are not familiar with game development, I have to also tell you that velocity.y*Gdx.graphics.getDelta()  with velocity.y=1 will move the sprite horizontally by 1 every second.

Comment: Does the bulletVelocity should be update every frame the same as bulletPos cause the bullet is only moving like the rotation of the gun but not going anywhere.